# React app context state update does not allow navigation

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When this function is called the app's context should be updated and then the user redirected, however `navigate("/")` is never called. Is it because `appState.setUser(user)` triggers some kind of refresh ? If so how can i fix this ?

Here's the relevant code :

```
    const appState = useContext(AppStateContext);

    function register() {
    APIFetcher.register(name, email, role, password)
        .then((user) => {
            appState.setUser(user)
            navigate("/")
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
}
```

Comment: Does it work without `appState.setUser(user)`?

Comment: Yes, without "appState.setUser(user)" everything works as it should.

Comment: You have to show your router configuration and how it the `AppStateContext` related to the router